# How to store safely credentials to the mysql database and secrets

Tags: python, flask

It bothers me that I have no idea how to store connection credentials to the mysql database and secrets for my flask app safely. Actually, I store them in plain text using environmental variables. I get those variables using python os module getenv. Also, I'm using uwsgi + nginx to serve my flask app. My goal is to prevent a hacker from accessing the database if he breaks into the server with mysql credentials (I got on my mysql server IP bind, however he can still execute the mysql request from the server).

I tried encrypting these variables and decrypting them on uwsgi startup by passing arguments, but it's not safe. I thought about using a shell script that ask me for a decryption key, then it runs a python script that decrypts credentials and saves them to a temp file. Then I run my app service and I delete the temp file with decrypted credentials. The second option seems good, but I want your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to prevent a hacker from accessing the database if he breaks into the server with mysql credentials (I got on my mysql server IP bind, however he can still execute the mysql request from the server).

Ultimately, this is not possible. You want your application to be able to access the database, but not access the credentials - you *can't* do that.

Separating it in environment variables allows you do separate logic and configuration, making secrets management easier - by e.g. having a common docker image without any state or secrets.

But ultimately the application needs passwords in clear text. You can encrypt them, but then you need to pass the key. Thus, you make it more or less hard, but you can't make it impossible.